# How to use Interface or Type in node_modules in .d.ts file

Tags: node.js, typescript

How to use `Interface` or `Type` in `node_modules` in `.d.ts` file
In my project, i need to create some `d.ts` files . Usually, I will use the `string`, `number` and other data types provided by `ts`, but there are also cases where I need to reference the types defined in the package. How do I reference them?

I tried to use `import type {xxx} from 'xxx'` but failed

and I also tried to use `/// <reference types="xxx" />`, but not very good at using

Comment: `import {x} from 'y'`

Comment: @hoangdv If I use `import {x} from 'y'`, the entire `d.ts` file will become invalid, prompting `Cannot find name 'SomeType'`